# MediaTimeline keeps playing after closing Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
        MediaTimeline timeline = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@path, UriKind.Relative));
        MediaClock clock = timeline.CreateClock();
        System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer player = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        player.Clock = clock;
        VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing();
        drawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
        drawing.Player = player;
        DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
        New_WEBMPlayer_Wnd.Background = brush;
```

which is run with a new Window for playing that specific file... The problema is that if I close the Window, the sound keeps playing. So I guess the video too. How to stop it after closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the player via `clock` since the player is now controlled by its `Clock`. If you stop the player directly (not via `Clock`) you will get an `InvalidOperationException`.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform this operation while a clock is assigned to the media player.

First, make the clock [controllable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605941(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
MediaClock clock = timeline.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock;
```

And you stop the player like this,

```
if (clock.CurrentState != ClockState.Stopped)
{
    clock.Controller.Stop();
}
```

To sum up, the working code looks like this

```
MediaTimeline timeline = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@path, UriKind.Relative));
MediaClock clock = timeline.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock; //make the clock controllable
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Clock = clock;
VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing();
drawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
drawing.Player = player;
DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
New_WEBMPlayer_Wnd.Background = brush;

//stop the clock when player window is closed
New_WEBMPlayer_Wnd.Closed += (s, e) =>
{
    if (clock.CurrentState != ClockState.Stopped)
    {
        clock.Controller.Stop();
    }
};
```