# MediaPlayer doesn't play sound in storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, storyboard

I am trying to play a sound synchronized to an animation that I am running in a storyboard.
So first I create a MediaEventObject in my ViewModel (I am using a MVVM pattern):

```
   private MediaElement _mediaElementObject;

    public MediaElement MediaElementObject
    {
        get { return _mediaElementObject; }
        set { _mediaElementObject = value; OnPropertyChanged("MediaElementObject"); }
    }
```

The XAML looks like this:

```
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MediaElementObject}"/>
```

In the respective meothod I create an instance of the Storyboard and the MediaElementObject:

```
            sb = new Storyboard();
            MediaElementObject = new MediaElement();
```

A little later I add the MediaElement to the storyboard:

```
        MediaTimeline mtl = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@"./Resources/Sounds/Ka-ching.Wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        mtl.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mtl, MediaElementObject);
        sb.Children.Add(mtl);
        sb.Begin();
```

There are additional doubleanimations in my storyboard, which I don't show here. But the sound never plays. The resource Ka-Ching.wav is set to "emmbedded resource" and "copy to output directory".

Comment: take a look at this post.. at least this OP got his to play but not stop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198486/mediatimeline-keeps-playing-after-closing-window

Comment: In that post they are not using a storyboard. Without storyboard I can get the sound to play.

Comment: Is Ka_ching.wav copied to the output directory or included as a resource?

Comment: It is included as an embedded resource

Comment: Try to set "Build action" as "Copy".

Comment: It was set to "Copy if newer" I changed it to "Always Copy" - doesn't work.

Comment: Strange - works for me with Build action "embedded resource" or "content" and "copy". Have you tried "Content"?

Comment: I tried to play it in a mediaplayer with the full path - it plays.
I then tried to use the full path in the mediatimeline - doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have to set the datacontext to the view model in the MainWindow:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

        ViewModel _ViewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
        _ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _ViewModel;
    }
```